# How can I add money?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble, I'm a new programmer (obviously) and I was wanting to make a wallet program to keep track of my money since I don't have a bank account. I want my money to add up correctly, but it just combines the words. Also I wanna know how to store that number, so when I leave and come back it'll be the same number.

Heres my code: (Very bad and prototype)

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> JavaScript Wallet </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<h2>Wallet</h2>

<script language="Javascript">

var plusCash = prompt("How much money are you entering?");

var money = 0.00;

var money = money + plusCash;

document.write("You have $" + money);
</script>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: This question seems like it is far, far too broad. The answer would require an introduction to dynamic languages, server setup, databasing, forms, javascript, and pretty much *everything* associated with online development.

Comment: What you've posted isn't proper HTML5, as you're using uppercase tag names, the obsolete `language` attribute, and the now-illegal `document.write`. Just saying.

Comment: You could probably use `localStorage` to keep the value between page loads.

Comment: 1. Missing doctype, 2. inconsistent case of HTML tags, 3. `language` attribute, 4. global variables, 5. `document.write`. This is fun.

Comment: rather than document.write, try using innerHTML or innerText on an element.

Comment: Hey, it's one thing to be missing that on some code by an acknowledged beginner... I spent most of November fixing issues like that on templates that came with a commercial shopping cart that a client spent $1800 on.

Answer (score 4):

Since `prompt` returns a `string` value, 'adding' that to a float results in a string - Javascript implicitly converts the float since it gives least data loss. To treat `plusCash` as a `float` value, invoke `parseFloat` on it:

```
var money = money + parseFloat(plusCash);
```

Answer (score 2):

To persist values between pages and browser sessions, you can use either cookies for short simple values, or `localStorage`, which was introduced in the HTML5-wave of platform enhancements.

Cookies would not be ideal in this situation because I'm guessing you're using HTML files on disk, therefore `localStorage` would be better.

`localStorage` is used thusly:

```
window.localStorage['someValue'] = someOtherValue;
```

`localStorage` can only store strings, not complex types (objects). You must 'stringify' / serialize them first, but this is easy:

```
window.localStorage['someObject'] = JSON.stringify( someObjectValue );
```

Note this code requires a fairly modern browser (think IE10, Chrome or recent builds of Firefox).